# PDF not downloading MVC dotnet core 3.1 "Couldn't download" error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation

Serving a pdf file from a MVC 3.1 controller generates a "Couldn't download - Network error" message but there aren't any errors on the server and the response headers appear to have the correct data (screenshot attached).

### browser screenshot/ response headers

[image]

### Controller code

This appears to be one of the acceptable ways to accomplish this.

```
  [HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Download([FromForm] IFormCollection formCollection)
  {
     ...
       // rawPdf is a byte[]
        var rawPdf = await _pdfFileService.GetMergedPdfFilesAsync(mergedFileName, pdfDirectoryPath, pathList);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ms.Write(rawPdf, 0, rawPdf.Length);
        //fix
        ms.Position = 0;

       // also tried
       //return File(ms, "application/pdf", mergedFileName);

        return new FileStreamResult(ms, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf"))
        {
            FileDownloadName = mergedFileName
        };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha! Bonehead issue. This was the fix: `ms.Position = 0`.

Explanation: the stream was at the end so when it was trying to flush it out, it was already at the end. The above line of code resets the stream to the starting position so it can be streamed.

Comment: Haha, yup, been there.